Can I stop my wife from flying flags in a home we co-own?
Justice Alito refuses to recuse himself from Jan. 6 cases after flag controversies
Justice Alito's impartiality was called into question because at various points, some flags with political symbolism were flown in his house. He still maintains he's impartial, because the flags were flown by his wife and not him.
I find this particular paragraph in Justice Alito's letter surprising:

The first incident cited in your letter concerns the flying of an upside-down American flag outside the house in Virginia where my wife and I reside. In considering whether this event requires recusal, an unbiased and reasonable person would take into account the following facts. As I have stated publicly, I had nothing whatsoever to do with the flying of that flag. I was not even aware of the upside-down flag until it was called to my attention. As soon as I saw it, I asked my wife to take it down, but for several days, she refused.
My wife and I own our Virginia home jointly. She therefore has the legal right to use the property as she sees fit, and there were no additional steps that I could have taken to have the flag taken down more promptly.

It seems bizarre that being joint owners of a house means you get to do stuff with the house against the other owner's wishes - if this argument were valid, then because it is symmetric, they also get to do stuff with the house against your wishes (which presumably including taking down the flags).
Does the law say that Justice Alito's wife has the legal right to use the property as she sees fit, including flying flags that Justice Alito cannot take down?

"Does the law say that Justice Alito's wife has the legal right to use the property as she sees fit, including flying flags that Justice Alito cannot take down?" The law is rarely that specific.  Especially when it comes to granting permission for behavior and controlling personal interactions between spouses.

Well, if it is a joint home and one co-owner cannot tell the other co-owner what to do or not to do, he could have taken it down himself. And his wife could not have done anything about it according to the first sentence. But that is common sense and common sense and the law don't mix well. Personally, "my wife hung it there and I'm not getting into trouble with my wife for no good reason" would have been the better, more convincing argument, legality aside.

@nvoigt I'd have thought so too, but Justice Alito surely knows more about laws than me (hence the question).

He's a Supreme Court justice. Surely he knows the law on this :)

Their house, her flag
There are all sorts of non-legal reasons why he might not have taken down the flag. Right off the bat I can think of two: he might have been away, or he might not have wanted to have a fight with his wife (I know I don’t).
However, focusing on just the legal questions:

Yes, any co-owner has the right to use the property in any way they like as long as they don’t damage it. The conventions that govern how co-owners live in the same property are social, not legal.
The flag may not be common property. If his wife owned the flag, then he has no right to touch it against her wishes.


"No right to touch" seems too strong. Suppose by analogy that a friend comes to visit my house and accidentally leaves behind his coat on a chair. Are you suggesting that I must leave it there without touching it until he comes back, and that it would be illegal for me to pick it up and hang it on the coat rack?

Could he remove the flagpole as long as he doens't touch the flag itself?

@Barmar removing the flagpole might reduce the value of the property.
